# Array.each_with_index doesn't run as expected

Tags: ruby

I redefined `Array#replace` like follows.

```
require 'test/unit'  
class Array  
  def replace (from, to)  
    each_with_index do |e, i|  
      self[i] = to if e = from  
    end  
  end  
end  

class TestDriver <Test::Unit::TestCase  
  def test_replace  
    book_topic = ['html', 'java', 'css']  
    book_topic.replace('java', 'ruby')  
    result_topic = ['html', 'ruby', 'css']  
    assert_equal book_topic, result_topic  
  end  
end
```

When I run that test case, it asserts the `book_topic` is `['html', 'ruby', 'ruby']`. I have no idea about the result of `book_topic`. Can anyone tell me why?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You missed an `=` in `e == from`.

```
self[i] = to if e == from
```

PS: I hope you know the pros/cons of overriding core methods like this.

Comment: ohhhhhh. I'm foolish...  Yes, I know I'm overriding a core class. Thank you very very much!

Comment: @madper Based on your comment, you should probably mark this as the answer.

Comment: @CharlesCaldwell, Sure. Sorry for late. When I mark this as answer, it said I should wait 9minutes. And I forget it after a while. I think I got Alzheimerdisease. :-)

Answer (score 2):

Consider using `map` or `map!` instead of overriding Array's replace method.

```
>> [1,2,3].map { |a| a == 1 ? 2 : a }
=> [2, 2, 3]
```